# NodeJS requests per second decreased by x4 times with NGINX + 5xx status code

Tags: node.js, express, nginx, optimization

**Hardware:**

Ubuntu 20.04 running on VMware Workstation Pro with 4 core CPU and 6GB of RAM

**Issue:**

After setting up my Nginx for my localhost NodeJS server the number of requests per second has decreased down to 13k from ~40k

Simulating the problem:

With help of [autocannon](https://www.npmjs.com/package/autocannon) I'm kind of DDoS attacking my server to monitor number of requests send and handled.

Here are the results **without** Nginx:

[image]

And here are the results **with** Nginx:

[image]

Where `1xx` `2xx` `3xx` `4xx` `5xx` are status code of the handled request

This is my `server.js` file:

```
const morgan = require('morgan')
const express = require('express')

const app = express();

app.use(morgan('dev'))

app.use('/', async (_, req) => {
    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve(), 0));
    req.send("success")
});

app.listen(3333)
```

**/etc/nginx/sites-available/default** file:

```
server {

  listen 80 default_server;
  listen [::]:80 default_server;

  root /var/www/html;

  # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
  index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

  server_name _;

  location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3333; // tried localhost:3333 too
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
  }

}
```

Here is my **nginx.conf**

[image]

So basically I'm trying to attack my server with 9k simultaneous connections while nginx.conf is restrained up to 10k - I'm getting **5xx** status code with nginx (in the picture attached above)

What am I doing wrong?

Is there a logical explanation and solution for why Nginx slowed down my application?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Actually, everything should work ok.
Nginx makes its job insane! It's a great tool against DDoS attacks which prevents multiple requests from the same IP address. Just read this documentation:  [rate limit](https://www.nginx.com/blog/rate-limiting-nginx/)

The reason my server is handling fewer requests per second and errors like `5xx` is because of Nginx's rate limit!